# Explaining the difference between sklearn's scale() and multiplying by STD and adding the mean

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm running sklearn's PCA `fit_transform()` function on some data I'm looking to analyze, and I'm having trouble figuring out how exactly I need to transform scaled data back into numbers that make sense within the context of what I'm running.  More specifically, when I run:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from sklearn.preprocessing import scale

X_scaled = scale(otr_df)

X_scaled2 = otr_df.sub(otr_df.mean())
X_scaled2 = X_scaled2.div(otr_df.std())

# Should print all zeroes
print (X_scaled - X_scaled2)/X_scaled

"""
The above prints the following:

Date              Index1         Index2            Index3          Index4
2016-05-11        0.000706       0.000706          0.000706        0.000706 ...
2016-05-10        0.000706       0.000706          0.000706        0.000706 ...
2016-05-09        0.000706       0.000706          0.000706        0.000706 ...
2016-05-06        0.000706       0.000706          0.000706        0.000706 ...
.                 .              .                 .
.                 .              .                 .
.                 .              .                 .
"""
```

Instead of zero (as I would expect), I am getting constant values of 0.000706 for every column when the bottom line of the above code is printed.  Although small, it doesn't seem like that is trivial if I am multiplying by several thousand to get back to the original scale (which I am in some cases).  My guess is that it has to do with dividing by (N - 1) instead of N or something along those lines.  However, after too much time reading sklearn and pandas docs with nothing to show for it, I figured I would ask here if anyone had any idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sklearn uses zero degrees of freedom in their standard deviation calculation:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from sklearn.preprocessing import scale

np.random.seed([3,1415])
otr_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 10))
X_scaled = scale(otr_df)

X_scaled2 = otr_df.sub(otr_df.mean())
X_scaled2 = X_scaled2.div(otr_df.std(ddof=0))
#                                    ^
#                  Specify ddof here |

# Should print all zeroes
print (X_scaled - X_scaled2)/X_scaled

     0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0  0.0 -0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0
2 -0.0  0.0 -0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0
3  0.0  0.0  0.0 -0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0 -0.0  0.0  0.0
4  0.0 -0.0  0.0 -0.0 -0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
5 -0.0 -0.0  0.0  0.0 -0.0  0.0  0.0 -0.0  0.0  0.0
6  0.0 -0.0  0.0  0.0 -0.0 -0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
7 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0  0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0  0.0  0.0 -0.0
8  0.0  0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0  0.0 -0.0 -0.0  0.0 -0.0
9  0.0  0.0 -0.0 -0.0  0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0
```

Comment: Ahh, I knew it would be something to do with the degrees of freedom.  Thanks for the answer.